# Writing permessions for linux kernel module paramater

Tags: module, linux-kernel

I have a module i created in linux kernel.
I want the module to receive parameters, and i want one of them to have reading and writing permissions.
So i defined :

```
module_param(param, int, S_IWUSR|S_IRUGO);
```

But for some reason when i go to /sys/module/mymodule/paramter/param and try to write to it does not give me permission (even using sudo)

Comment: How do you *write*?  `echo 1 > debug` works with `static int debug; module_param(debug, int, 0600);`.  Did you declare `static int param;`?

Comment: Does the error say permission denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use `sudo` with `echo` like

```
sudo echo 1 > /sys/module/mymodule/paramter/param
```

this?

Redirection to a file does not work with `sudo`. Use e.g. `tee` instead:

```
echo 1|sudo tee /sys/module/mymodule/paramter/param
```

That way you can write to a file as root.

Apart from that, your `module_param()` call looks good.

Comment: Thanks that worked. why is the only way that i can edit the file?
shouldn't it work like any file i want to edit?

Comment: @user690936 Kinda late, but FWIW: “Another thing tee can help you is to avoid one problem when using sudo. The normal output redirection operator is always executed with your user privileges, also when you write a sudo in front of the command which generates the STDOUT text.” [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/408348)